# Creating a new column of values based on another column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of values with multiple columns. One of the columns contains values under the format "X-Y" (values are not numerical. There are no other hyphens/"-"s in X or Y. The only hyphen is the separator). I would like to create a new column that contains specific values depending on what X is in this one column.

For example, if X = 'egg', I want it to print out 'bacon' in the column next to it. If X = 'duck', I want the value in the column next to it to be 'bird' instead.

If column A held value egg-quack, I would want the column B next to it to print out bacon. If column A held value egg-duck, I would still want column B to contain the value bacon. If column A held value duck-duck, column B would contain the value bird.

I hope this is clear. How would I be able to go about doing this?

I'm not too familiar with data handling in general, so if there are other more effective methods other than VBA, I'm also willing to look into that.
Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like a formula with `split`, `vlookup`, and `concat` would be able to do that for you

Comment: If you wanted to do vba i’d use a dictionary and then it’s a simple key value pair deal if it’s just one value related to one other value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use VLOOKUP for this, with FIND to locate the hyphen:

[image]